# Show Progress bar when user control cause postback in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, progress-bar

In my web application have user control(gridview) inside html table earch row and I want to show progress bar when user control(gridview) cause postback at pageIndexChange event. Also help me to prevent main page postback when usercontrol PageIndexChange event trigger if possible.

Comment: tried, ajax update panel but it doesn't stop main page postback

Comment: can you show your code?